# I need some information about vintage tube amplifiers

Tags: amplifier

Editing My question again.

I need a Little HISTORY about Tube Amplifiers or Tube Sound,

need Signal Processing theory of the same, Its Schematics

and

importantly need how it is RE-Modeled into a DSP Plugin. (either by Programming or Capturing Impulse Responses)

Please Help me..

THANK YOU.

Comment: Please specify your question. For e.g. do you need Information on how to use tube amplifiers or how they are constructed? Also DSP Plug-Ins and recreation is a very complex work field that requires a lot of studying, so you might start out by buying a theoretical book about programming plug-ins or capturing impulse responses. Also the concept of physical modelling might be a keyword for your research.

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific as to what you are after. Information could mean anything... Do you want schematics, model numbers, pictures? If you put in a bit more effort with your question we can help you better.

As you don't go into details of what you are doing or why you are doing it, it is difficult to provide useful info, but one method could be taking impulse responses of existing cabinets, another could be modelling the amp using filters and waveshaping to model the response of the tube. Look those up and see if they're what you are after.